# Adding extra column in the middle of the row while appending it in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find some answer, but all I found is not regarding my problem. Can someone please tell me how I can append row into other row at the same time adding some extra column?

So far I have something like this:

```
for row in reader_action[0]:
    action_res.append([row[0:2],0,row[2:]])
```

and the output is:

```
[['1', '2'], 0, ['3', '4', '5']]
```

but what I am looking for is:

```
['1', '2', 0, '3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I think you want:

```
for row in reader_action[0]:
    action_res.append([row[0:2] + [0] + row[2:]])
```

Comment: Yes, but it looks that it should be: `action_res.append(row[0:2] + [0] + row[2:])`. It works then correctly.